# Android check days between two day-times

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

Hello everyone i try to check between days two daytimes
i have for example 12/10/2014 and 12/15/2015 datetimes.I wrote some code witch can to check different days between there two daytimes
this is a my source

```
    public String getDateDiffString(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
    long timeOne = dateOne.getTime();
    long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
    long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    long delta = (timeTwo - timeOne) / oneDay;

    if (delta > 0) {

        return String.valueOf(delta);
    } else {
        delta *= -1;
        return String.valueOf(delta);
    }
}
```

this code working perfect but i want to increase days for example 12/10/2014, 12/11,2014.....12/20/2014 between first and second daytimes.i i also wrote code but result is between first date and second days -1(between 12/19/2014)
this is a my source

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date _d;
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat new_df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");

                _d = df.parse(timeInfo.getTimeformat().get(0));
                Date _d1 = df.parse(timeInfo.getEndTimeFormat().get(0));
                String datetimeis = getDateDiffString(_d1, _d);
                int differentdays = Integer.parseInt(datetimeis);
                Log.e("Different is ", "" + differentdays);
                for (int k = 0; k < differentdays; k++) {


                    String datetimeformat = dateFormatter(timeInfo.getStartTimePeriod().get(0)); 

                    Date datetime = new_df.parse(datetimeformat);

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(datetime);
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, k);

                    datetime = cal.getTime();

                    String ttime = new_df.format(datetime);
                    ApishaDaysAdapter.add(ttime);
                    ApishaHollsAdapter.add(timeInfo.getHole());

                    String start_time = timeInfo.getTime();
                    start_time = start_time.replace(",", "\n");
                    ApishaTimesAdapter.add(start_time);
                    timeInfo.setStartTimePeriod(ttime);
                    System.out.println(ttime);

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

how i can solve my problem?if anyone knows solution please help me
i want to increase days [12 -20] and not [12-19)

Comment: for (int k = 0; k <= differentdays; k++)

Comment: This is a sloved problem - no need to wrtie/maintain your own versio, Use the Joda Time library http://www.joda.org/joda-time/